# how to convert char array to integer in C?

Tags: c, string, char, type-conversion

How can I convert the char array `x` to an integer **89** in the code below? Thank you

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    char y[13] = "0123456789012";
    char x[3];
    int integer_value;

    x[0] = y[8];
    x[1] = y[9];
    x[3] = '\0';

    integer_value=atoi(x);
}
```

Comment: Should be `x[2] = '\0';`, rather than `x[3]`, but apart from that, that works. What is the question?

Comment: Should be `x[2] = '\0';`, `x[3]` is out of bounds.

Comment: the code you wrote does exactly what you are asking... just x[2]='\0'

Comment: Also, `y` is one too short as there is a null character in a string literal.

Comment: sorry, I don't know how I missed x[3] :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're done; `atoi()` is one way of doing the conversion from a string to an integer. You could also use `strtol()` or `sscanf()`.

**UPDATE:** Assuming, of course, that you fix the termination, i.e. set `x[2] = '\0';` rather than `x[3]`.